# Drop row where integer column equals value fails

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where the datatypes are:-

```
> dfg.dtypes

std      float64
label     object
count      int64
dtype: object
```

But when I try to drop columns where count=1 I get the following error:-
Can anyone explain?
Thanks

```
> dfg = dfg[dfg.count != 1]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   1944             try:
-> 1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   1946             except KeyError:

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4154)()
```

etc.

Comment: `df.count` - is a pandas method, so try this: `dfg = dfg[dfg['count'] != 1]`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there's a problem naming a column "count".
If I change the column name to "mycount" it all works fine.
Sorry to bother you!